# How mongodb/axios url based ssl works

Tags: ajax, mongodb, ssl, axios, ssl-certificate

Browser has local certificates installed as public key to work with SSL, but mongodb provides SSL through url only (just need to add `+srv` with mongodb url).

So how does client authenticate secure data transfer?

Is it something that client (mongo shell or node js library) which use MongoDB SSL are pre-installed with those certificates?

I was having task to secure MongoDB data through SSL but not having answer to how this works as I knew how browser based https worked.

Axios like libraries also can communicate using SSL. So do they use same mechanism like Mongodb url uses?